# Keep the BottomAppBar when pushing a new screen

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I'm developing a Flutter app that has always a BottomAppBar visible with just two tabs.
Navigating through these two tabs is working fine, but I would like to push a new screen while tapping on the appBar and on one of the tile I have on one of the tab.

I've already tryied the Navigator but, when pushing a new screen, the BottomAppBar disappear

Here is the relevant code:

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'DemoApp',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: ...,
        home: HomePage());
  }
}
```

home_page.dart

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('DemoApp'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              tooltip: "Account settings",
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserDetail('test')));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: WalletTab(),
        bottomNavigationBar: FABBottomAppBar(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
          onTabSelected: _selectedTab,
          selectedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          notchedShape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          items: [
            FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.home, text: 'Wallet'),
            FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.location_on, text: 'Store')
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            tooltip: '',
            ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false);
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I've pushed the project here on github: https://github.com/punkeroso/demo

Any advice?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In these cases consider trying Bottom Navigation bar instead, I'ts much more easier to achieve a fixed bar while navigating between multiple pages this way.
I don't think you can find a way for this otherwise, and if there is it'll be inefficient.

Comment: Unfortunely I can't, I need the notched shape of the BottomAppBar...

Answer (score 0):

you could use PageView instead of navigating to new route or else you may use auto_route package which has built-in PageView .

```
AutoTabsRouter.pageView(            
 routes: [            
    BooksTab(),            
    ProfileTab(),            
    SettingsTab(),            
    ],           
 builder: (context, child, _) {            
    final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);      
    return Scaffold(            
          appBar: AppBar(            
          title: Text(context.topRoute.name),            
          leading: AutoLeadingButton()),            
          body: child,            
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(                
                currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,                
                onTap: tabsRouter.setActiveIndex                
                items: [                
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Books',...),                
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Profile',...),                
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Settings',...),                
                ],                
              ),          
        ),            
  ); },
```

);